# Wordpress: after add post Fatal Error memory limit

Tags: php, wordpress

when I try to add new post, after clicking "publish" I have this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /XXX/wp-includes/meta.php on line 776.
```

I spoken with my server admin and he can't give me more memory, so I tried to optimize WP by plugin WP-Optimize but this din't help.
I think wordprass is a good choice with alot of posts. Right now I have in wp_posts 5423 and wp_postmeta 32734 rows.(The website exists less than 1 year) 
Any suggestion can be helpful.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WP-Optimize won't solve your issue because its job is to clean the database.
You're PHP error has to do with the PHP Memory Limit.

If you have access to the code, then add the following in the "index.php" file of your Wordpress folder:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```

If you have access to the server's "php.ini" file, then change the following:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

It doesn't matter how big your database is. It's failing because your posting "probably" too much data (images, videos etc.) and it's going through a loop filling the memory, and when it reaches the limit, the script fails.
If it occurs every time you try to write a post, then you might want to look into the Wordpress plugins and their performance.

Comment: How should decreasing the allowed memory to 16 megs solve the underlying problem? Even the currently allowed 128 megs are exhausted. So the problem lies deeper burried somewhere in WPs settings IMHO.

Comment: As I said in post below, I cannot increase more memory limit. 
ini_set doesn't work too because I have limit on the server.

Comment: It all depends on the PHP version:
- before PHP 5.2.0, the default value is "8M"
- in PHP 5.2.0, the default value is "16M"
- after PHP 5.2.0, the default value is "128M"

I do agree that the number is low and it should be changed.
Also the user should check his machine's specs before modifying this value.

Comment: @MichałKalkowski Then it's time too move your Wordpress installation to another server ;)

If you really want to keep it in on the current server, then try to turn off all the plugins, and try to add a post. If the problem is still there, then the plugins have nothing to do with this bug. Your server might be the faulty here.

Also try to upgrade your Wordpress version to the most stable version.

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik 
can you recommend some server (or tell me what parameters should have the server to work on it WP websites with a large number of posts)? What happens in next year when my site have more posts? So I have to buy new server with more memory?

Comment: Check Digital Ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/
It's the cheapest hosting with state-of-the-art hardware (SSD etc.).
Check the animated video at the bottom of the homepage. You can install Wordpress in one click.

Comment: Thanks for help! The error disappear when I disabled all plugins. My next steps was enabled one by one so when I have 10 plugins enabled this error is displayed but when I disable one more error not show :)

Comment: @MichałKalkowski So most probably the error is related to one of your plugins. Try to enable each plugin on its own and check if the error still occurs. You'll be able to find out which one is causing the problem, and get rid of it. Remember that not all the plugins are optimized and stable. Also, keep your Wordpress version up-to-date.